# Smart Object Does Not Update

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, image-editing, smartobject

I attempted to paste a vector and/or image file on Photoshop as a smart object, when editing the image, it does not update on Illustrator.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you placed a linked PSD file in an Illustrator document? Maybe try opening the links panel, select the file you linked to, and hit the update button.

Comment: Copy/paste between applications **never** remembers the original application. Doesn't matter what application one is using. One must use a **Place** command to *link* to a file from another application, not copy/paste.

Comment: @Scott - I read this differently, but yeah pasting could be the problem. It's a really confusing question. Not entirely sure what the OP is actually trying to do here.

Comment: @BillyKerr - I suspect a language barrier a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Photoshop smart objects **do not** update external Illustrator files.

When one pastes... Photoshop *embeds* the vector data and creates a *separate* internal file for vector smart objects which has *no connection* to any external file. If you double-click a vector smart object and edit it, you are **not** editing the original Illustrator file. Note the title of the tab/window in Illustrator when editing...

[image]

It is **not** any .ai file you may have originally copied content from.

If you wish to use an external file from Illustrator, and have the photoshop file update when the Illustrator file changes, use `File > Place > Linked` in Photoshop rather than copy/pasting.